# Xcode 5: Pushing and pulling from new GitHub repository does not work

Tags: git, github, xcode5

On GitHub, I have deleted my existing repository and created a new one with the same name `Test`.

Now, when trying to push my local repository to GitHub for the first time, I get the error message: "Working copy out of date. Try pulling from the remote to get the latest changes, then push again."

And when trying to pull from GitHub, I get the error message: "`Test` is not a valid remote branch to pull from. Please choose a different remote branch."

I have only one branch, which is `master`.

How can I solve this issue with Xcode 5?

Comment: Does it work from the command line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I got this to work:

1. Deleted repository on GitHub.
2. Created a new repository with the same
   name, but did **not** include the `.gitIgnore` and `ReadMe` file recommended by
   GitHub.
3. Pushed the local repository using Xcode 5.

It works perfectly now!

Again: Do not include the `.gitIgnore` and `ReadMe` file from GitHub.

P.S. If someone else answers this question, I will selected his answer as the correct answer.

Comment: For those of you who were concerned as I was about loosing the history and submission info, fear not! When you push from Xcode everything is dandy and you don't loose any of the tree data

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I spent the last two hours trying to get my project to push to Github.